# Не выводится the_excerpt() поста в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот код вывода трех последних постов. У меня много рубрик, но этот код выводит последние три добавленные посты не зависимо в каких рубриках они находятся.

```
   $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 3
        );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);         
        if( $recent_posts ): 
              foreach($recent_posts as $post){
                $id = $post['ID'];
                $postDesc = get_the_excerpt($id);
                echo $postDesc;
              }
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
```

Не могу получить переменную $postDesc;
То есть не выводится get_the_excerpt($id);
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция используется только в цикле и не принимает аргументов.

Самый простой вариант

```
    args = array(
        'numberposts' => 3
    );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);         
    if( $recent_posts ): 
          foreach($recent_posts as $post){
            setup_postdata( $post );
            the_excerpt()
          }
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Не работает, не знаю почему.

Comment: Он запись выводит, но не соответствует посту.